# Update an existing ooxml file with C# and System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive

Tags: c#, zip

I am trying to update an nearly empty docx/ooxml file. I dont get an exception, the code is running through but the file is not modified.

I think I am missing something :/

The code below is not the actual code, but a simplified example. It is also running without an exception but the file is not updated.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(docxFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    var archive = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Update);

    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.Name == "[Content_Types].xml")
        {
            using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
            {
                var doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(entryStream);

                var element = doc.CreateElement("Override");
                element.SetAttribute("PartName", "/docProps/example.xml");

                doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(element);

                doc.Save(entryStream);
                entryStream.Flush();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it was late yesterday :(

Either use `using` with the `ZipArchive` instance or calling `Dispose` after the loop will do the job ;)

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(docxFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.Name == "[Content_Types].xml")
            {
                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    var doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(entryStream);

                    var element = doc.CreateElement("Override");
                    element.SetAttribute("PartName", "/docProps/example.xml");

                    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(element);

                    doc.Save(entryStream);
                    entryStream.Flush();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```